# JQuery smooth-scroll and nice-scroll

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I apologize, I know there are countless threads regarding this topic... I cannot seem to get any to work. I think I am calling the anchor wrong.

I am using a WordPress theme (SpaLab) which incorporates Jquery smooth-scroll and nice-scroll enabled.

My nav menu is essentially as follows:

```
<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="#home"> Home </a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="#contact"> Contact </a>
</li>
```

I have divs for each menu item as follows:

```
<div id="contact">
  contact section
</div>
```

I can't seem to smoothly scroll, animate, or get anything to work. Am I messing up the href and div id's or something? It's taken me hours to get nowhere.

Comment: Try adding this: `<a name="contact"></a>` at the top of the `#contact` div. Depending on how the smooth-scroll is implemented it may expect that syntax for the target. Other than that I think you'll need to post a link to your site for anyone to be able to guess what is wrong. Oh, and also: It's not particularly clear if it scrolls to the right place at all (ie. does scroll, just not smoothly), so maybe add that "detail" to your question.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for helping. It didn't work but that is really good to know. I just learned how to discover the event listener, I will find out how the scroll to top button works and see if I can mimic some functionality. Thank you, truly, so very kind. Thanks!